# Communicator from a Fragment to a Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I try to send 3 informations from a Fragment to the Dialog it calls, but when i try out my code, i get a nullPointerException at that Line with the called method (dataSave) after i triggered the Dialog and the communicator.

My MainActivity:

```
[...]public void onDataSave(int Note, String Fach, String Wahl) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SpeicherDialog f2 =(SpeicherDialog) manager.findFragmentByTag("speicherdialog");
    f2.
    dataSave
    (Note, Fach, Wahl);
}´
```

The ´SpeicherDialog´:

```
public class SpeicherDialog extends DialogFragment {
int    note;
String fach;
String wert;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle("Note speichern?")
        .setMessage("Willst du die Note " + note + " im Fach " + fach + "speichern?")
        .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // do nothing (will close dialog)
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Speichern",  new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                 // do something

                }
        })
        .create();
}

public void dataSave(int Note, String Fach, String Wahl) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    note = Note;
    fach = Fach;
    wert = Wahl;
}
```

}

and the Action, when the Dialog and communicator is triggered:

```
SpeicherDialog speicherDialog  = new SpeicherDialog();
             speicherDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "speicherdialog");
             comm.onDataSave(note, fach, wert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear, why are you using a listener to your MainActivity that calls "onDataSave" when you already have the fragment variable in your calling method?

You get a NullPointerException because the Fragment hasn't been added yet. The "show" method of a DialogFragment is asynchronous (it creates a FragmentTransaction and commits it). That's why the findFragmentByTag method returns null.

To get your code working, you simply need to replace the method that creates the dialog by this :

```
SpeicherDialog speicherDialog  = new SpeicherDialog();
speicherDialog.dataSave(note, fach, wert); 
speicherDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "speicherdialog");
```

To improve this code and take into account your dialog fragment's lifecycle, you should consider giving the parameters via the setArguments methods as shown in the example :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog

Comment: Thanks a lot I want to send the 3 informations from one Fragment, triggered by a Button in it, over the interface Communicator(onDataSave) in the MainActivity to the Dialog(dataSave) if this answer your question.

Comment: You don't need to pass through the Activity (Communicator) to give the information to your Dialog. Do it directly from the fragment with my above lines of code. You can still keep the call to the Communicator if it needs to do other stuff but passing arguments to a dialog fragment should be done at its creation (using the bundle ideally).